# Using Active Record structure.sql with Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a Rails 4.2.5 application with a MySQL 5.6 database. This MySQL database has a number of foreign keys, views and functions. Schema.rb is designed to be database agnostic and therefore can't support the database specific commands necessary to modify these additional schema objects so the structure.sql functionality is provided.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Unfortunately, the built in structure dump tasks for MySQL do not include procedures, triggers or foreign keys. This is problematic for our team as we have to manually version control these "non standard" objects. Therefore I decided to find a solution that would allow management of the entire database schema using migrations. I landed upon this nice post by Pivotol Labs.

https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/using-mysql-foreign-keys-procedures-and-triggers-with-rails

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :structure do |schema|
    schema[:dump].abandon
    desc 'OVERWRITTEN - shell out to mysqldump'
    task dump: :environment do
      config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
      filename = "#{Rails.root}/db/structure.sql"
      cmd = "mysqldump -u#{config['username']} -p#{config['password']} "
      cmd += '-d --routines --triggers --skip-comments '
      cmd += "#{config['database']} > db/structure.sql"
      system cmd
      File.open(filename, 'a') do |f|
        f << ActiveRecord::Base.connection.dump_schema_information
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'load the development_structure file using mysql shell'
    task load: :environment do
      config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
      cmd = "mysql -u#{config['username']} -p#{config['password']} "
      cmd += "#{config['database']} < db/structure.sql"
      system cmd
    end
  end

  namespace :test do |schema|
    schema[:clone_structure].abandon
    desc 'OVERWRITTEN - load the development_structure file using mysql shell'
    task clone_structure: %w(db:structure:dump db:test:purge) do
      config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['test']
      cmd = "mysql -u#{config['username']} -p#{config['password']} "
      cmd += "#{config['database']} < db/structure.sql"
      system cmd
    end
  end
end
```

By making use of mysqldump from the shell I can generate a structure.sql file that contains all of the schema objects.

Currently my main problem is on Heroku I can't locate mysql dump. I installed this buildpack which provides the MySQL binaries.

https://github.com/gaumire/heroku-buildpack-mysql

However I get the error

> mysqldump: not found

when running `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

As you can see I'm down quite the rabbit hole here. I suspect there's going to be a problem with Heroku's readonly file system anyway even if I can correctly locate mysqldump. Perhaps I should bypass non development environments in my overridden rake db:structure:dump task because structure.sql should contain a schema that's consistent across all my environments, so perhaps I can get away with not trying to write to it in production?

If anyone has managed to pull this off or has alternative approaches to managing a complete MySQL schema using Active Record migrations I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot this by running `heroku run bash -a <myapp>`, which will launch a bash shell in a one-off dyno with the same environment as you would get when running `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Heroku's file systems are not read only, they're "ephemeral". You can create/change files in a dyno but those changes are lost when the dyno is terminated, so changes do not persist, so this approach should work, provided that you can locate the `mysqldump` binary.